# Right carousel moves when i am using the left carousel?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, carousel, document-carousel

I have been trying to put a page together which has 2 carousels (besides each other). I already had one working so copied it and made changes to make it a new one. Everything looks fine but when i click it both move! I want them to behave separately.

Can you help please?

I can give more information if you need it.

Comment: Please post your code that initialises the instances.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to change the name of the second carousel